# Convergence of a Series with Squared Terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove: given $a_n\geq 0$, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n^2$ converges. If I were to investigate the sequence of partial sums of the original sequence, would the idea be to square each term of the sequence? Help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: If $0<a<1$ then $a^2<a$.

Comment: So since $\sum a_n$ converges, I know $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$. Is this what you are using to suppose $0<a<1$? I'm not seeing where that is coming from.

Comment: use definision of limit & $\varepsilon=1$

Comment: Yes. $0<a_n<1$ for all but finitely many values of $n$. Finitely many values don't affect convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges we know that $a_n$ is a null-sequence. Let $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_n|\le 1$ for all $n\ge m$. Then using $x^2\le |x|$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ we have
$$\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n^2 \le \sum_{n=m}^\infty |a_n| = \sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.$$
So $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n^2 $ is convergent and hence also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$.

Comment: How does convergence of $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n^2$ imply convergence of the entire series?

Comment: @Guest23 There are only finitely many terms missing. Finite series are called sums and converge always ;).

Comment: Ok thanks! My intuition tells me that, just wasn't sure if I had to be more precise!

Comment: @Guest23 If you want to argue precise you have to consider the two sequences of partial sums and use that they are off by $\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the $a_i$ are $\ge 0$ then
$$a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots +a_N^2\le (a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_N)^2.\tag{1}$$

The partial sums $\sum_1^N a_i$ are bounded above, and therefore by (1) so are the partial sums $\sum_1^N a_i^2$. These partial sums are non-decreasing, so they converge.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. $‎‎‎\exists‎ n_0$ such that $|a_n -0|=|a_n|<1$ for all $n_0 \leq n$ hence $a_{n}^2\leq a_n$ for for all $n_0 \leq n$.